# RAILS: Using simple_form with parent/child accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, parent

I am using simple_form on a project where I have the following associations

```
Company  
  has_many :users 
  has_many :projects
User  
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :tasks
Project 
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :tasks
Task  
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
```

I am using a simple_form association input like so:

```
<%= f.association :user, :prompt => "Assign To...", :label_method => :first_name, :value_method => :id %>
```

But I need it to list ONLY the users who have the correct company_id (the same that the project belongs to). Is there a way to do this? I have done some googling and have come up with nothing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an in-line way to handle it:

```
<%= f.association :user, :collection => User.where(:company_id => current_user.company_id), :prompt => "Assign To...", :label_method => :first_name, :value_method => :id %>
```

Only shows users who's company_id match that of the current user (which matches that of the project)

Answer (score 0):

You should extract all the users , that belong to the company , and pass it to the list for assignment , is that right ? In your method (helper or model)

```
@company = Company.find(params[:id])
@labors = @company.users
```

It should return an array of instance objects , which you can use in the list .

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to handle it in line, though. I've posted my answer.